# How exactly can we interact with people resurrected by the resurrection stone?

Tags: harry-potter

I mean to ask that we know that resurrection stone brings people nearly back from the death . So how exactly can we interact with a person who is "livelier than a ghost but less than alive"? I mean we can talk and see (partially) the ghosts, but the resurrected persons are more than a ghost. So what are the additional ways we can interact with them?

Answer (score 2):

## Speech

As you mentioned, you can talk to the resurrected person - as we see when Harry talks to

> Lupin, Sirius, and his parents.

## Sight

You can *see* the person you called back - they're not just a disembodied voice.

## Physical Contact

<sub>(This part is probably what answers your question the most.)</sub>

As we see when Harry summons

> Lupin, Sirius, Lily, and James,

the people interact with the world around them -

> He knew it had happened, because he heard slight movements around him that suggested frail bodies shifting their footing on the earthy, twig-strewn ground that marked the outer edge of the forest.
> <sub>*Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows*, chapter 34: "The Forest Again"</sub>