# What would happen if someone tried to resurrect Voldemort using the Resurrection Stone?

Tags: harry-potter, magical-items

I know there is probably no direct cannon to support any hypotheses made, but I have been mulling the question over in my head for some time and cannot come up with a fully satisfactory answer.

The books say that the Resurrection Stone allows one to see and converse with those who have 'passed on'. It therefore implies that it is the soul of the departed that is being communicated with but as we all (hopefully) know, Voldemort split his soul into a total of eight pieces, so what would happen if someone somehow found the Stone in the forest where Harry dropped it and decided to have a little chit-chat with The Dark Lord?

In Harry's out-of-body/in-head experience he saw the small baby-thing and Dumbledore told him that it was Voldemort's mangled soul.

so would our random discoverer see a curled up mangled-soul figure? Would they see eight such creatures? Would they see one whole and complete Voldemort as all the pieces of his soul somehow combine again once all are re-united in the 'afterlife? Or do people have other theories on how the Stone allows conversations with the dead?

Comment: Your best bet for a canon answer is probably to ask JKR on twitter, as there's (currently) no canon information, and she's been known to answer fan questions from time to time.

Answer (score 5):

When Voldemort split his could into eight pieces, he was still able to function out of his body, using only one of these pieces.  The part of him that we saw in King's Cross is the part that was attached to Harry, so it's safe to assume that all the rest of his soul has 'passed on' as well.

We have no canon answer to this question, everything is speculation, but I don't see a reason why Voldy wouldn't come back as normal.  Sure, it would only be 1/8th of his soul, unless he felt remorse in the end, but he would be there.  It might look like a mangled-soul creature or not, we really have no idea.  But the pieces of his soul would not rearrange into one dude unless he felt remorse as he died.

Comment: And this is assuming the Resurrection Stone even *works as described*, something I have yet to get an answer to.  A duplication (like a ghost or a painting) *seems* a lot like the original soul, but isn't.

Comment: @Terriblefan I was about to direct you to your own question.... http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/117769/does-the-resurrection-stone-really-bring-peoples-spirits-back-or-just-duplic/117777#117777

Comment: @Skooba I'm still not satisfied. I was hoping Rowling would have said something about it.

Comment: @Terriblefan I know right! I was going to say well, here is what we know / can speculate, but realized you should be aware of it already....

Comment: What's left of Voldemort might not actually have passed on, I'm guessing that it's still stuck in the "between place" Harry saw as King's Cross.  The Resurrection Stone might or might not work in that case.  (I wonder if it works on ghosts?)

Comment: @Harry A very good point, I never thought about ghosts. I always hypothesised that the stone works by creating 'temporary ghosts' as it were, basically calling a person's "spirit" or soul back temporarily until they're 'let go' again so it might not work on ghosts as their "spirits" or souls or whatever make up ghosts are on earth already. Again, all speculation on how the stone and ghosts work.

Comment: @Harry Also, you make an interesting point about Voldermort's 1/8th soul being stuck in the in-between, I wonder if all of his soul pieces are stuck in the void between life and death because it suggests that no incomplete soul is able to completely pass on

Comment: Back to the original answer, if we assume that all pieces of Voldy's soul are 'reachable' by the stone, why would only 1/8th of the soul be recalled, I agree that the soul could not be merged again unless he repented (let's face it a near impossible feat for Tom) but if the stone were able to bring what's left of him back (again, many assumptions on how the stone works) how would it be able to distinguish between the separate pieces and decide "right, I'm going to show you and none of you"? I'm more and more inclined to believe that it might just summon back all pieces separately

Comment: @Sasuke'sBrother: it is my understanding that the other 7 pieces have been destroyed, not passed on.  Hermione said something to that effect, if I remember rightly.

Comment: @HarryJohnston That is correct.  In chapter 6 of DH, Hermione said " The fragment of soul inside it depends on its container, its enchanted body, for survival.  It can’t exist without it.”   But it also seems like the soul just dies, as the bit of Voldemort inside the diary did.  I'm not sure what to think here.